# Spring-data-mongodb save localdatetime with different time zone

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, localdatetime

I have a spring boot application that uses spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb (2.7.7) to link with a local mongodb (v6). I have two different classes (with a LocalDateTime property) that maps two different collections; my problem is that the LocalDateTime property of the two classes are saved like they come from different timezone in the rispective mongo collection.

**First class/collection**

Class

```
@Document("CollectionOne")
public class ClassOne{
@Id
private String id;
private LocalDateTime dataChiamata;
```

Repo

```
public interface ClassOneRepo extends MongoRepository<ClassOne, String>{}
```

Saving

```
classOneRepo.save(obj1);
```

Obj1.dataChiamata ( from debugger )

[image]

MongoDb CollectionOne:  exact same date of java 
[image]

**Second class/collection**

Class

```
@Document("CollectionTwo")
public class ClassTwo{
@Id
private String id;
private List<LocalDateTime> giorniLetti;
```

Repo

```
public interface ClassTwoRepo extends MongoRepository<ClassTwo, String> {}
```

Saving

```
classTwoRepo .save(obj2);
```

Obj2.giorniLetti.get(0) (from debugger) 
[image]

MondoDB CollectionTwo: one hour previous respect the java

[image]

I don't understand why the two dates are saved in a different way on the db although they are exactly the same java object; any suggestion?

Comment: Show us the code that populates the object fields.

Comment: I suggest you switch from `LocalDateTime` to `Instant` which is independent of a timezone.